# Run exe in background

Tags: powershell

I've tried the following:

```bsh
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "C:\Program Files\Prometheus.io\prometheus.exe" -WindowStyle hidden
```

```bsh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -AsJob -ScriptBlock {
    'C:\Program Files\Prometheus.io\prometheus.exe'
}
```

```bsh
Start-Job -Name "prometheus" -ScriptBlock {Get-Process prometheus.io}
```

```bsh
Start-Job {& .\prometheus.exe}
```

Sometimes it starts but terminates immediately after starting. If I start it manually it works correctly.

How can I keep my process alive in background?

---

EDIT :

It doesn't worked because i wasn't in the directory of my process that need a file which pathfile is not set.

Comment: Your syntax for Start-Process is wrong, you don't need to reference powershell, just launch your program with the WindowStyle param set like this: `Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Prometheus.io\prometheus.exe" -WindowStyle Hidden`

Comment: It doesn't work, my process stop right away...

Comment: Nevermind it doesn't worked because I wasn't in the directory and my process can't start correctly because he have a default argument that must be changed if i'm not in the directory. Thanks !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your syntax for Start-Process is wrong, you don't need to reference powershell, just launch your program with the `WindowStyle` param set

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Prometheus.io\prometheus.exe" -WindowStyle Hidden
```

The `WorkingDirectory` param can also be used to start the program in a specific directory

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Prometheus.io\prometheus.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Program Files\Prometheus.io" -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Comment: Does this allow you to close the terminal you run this command in AND still have the process running, or is it tied to the terminal you run this in?