# Run docker in background under Powershell

Tags: powershell, docker, background, execute, start-job

Simple question, I want to run docker command in background.
(Actually running any command with command line parameters under Powershell is my real question, but `docker` is a simple concrete one)

I have a command

```
docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY firefox
```

which runs fine under Powershell, but it blocks.

I want to runs the equivalent method of doing "&" as under *nix:

```
docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY firefox &
```

I've tried

- [Run exe in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222004/)
- [Powershell equivalent of bash ampersand (&) for forking/running background processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185575)

but neither works for me:

```
> ping google.com &
At line:1 char:17
+ ping google.com &
+                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed.

> Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe" run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY firefox
Start-Process : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'e' is ambiguous. Possible
matches include: -ErrorAction -ErrorVariable.
At line:1 char:86
+ ... Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe" run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY ...
+                                                                ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Tried to wrap the whole command within `Start-Process { ... }` doesn't work either.

**[UPDATE/Summary]**

The accepted answers works (after I removed "`-ti`" from the command line), as @nischay goyal has put, *"please don't use -it as it opens the terminal and blocks it."*. The error I got was:

```
the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (the input devic...d with 'winpty':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

- So `Start-Job` *might* not fit as a general purpose way of doing "`&`", e.g., if I want to start `bash &` that way.
- However, the `Start-Process` works after passing all the rest of `docker` command line parameters to the `-ArgumentList` parameter as a single string.
- And of course, like all docker/Linux camp people say, use `-d`.

All in all, there are many ways to solve the problem. Pick the one that suits you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Start-Job) to run a command in the background in PowerShell.**

In PowerShell [Core] 6+, you can also place `&` at the end of your command, the same way you can in POSIX-like shells such as Bash.

In both cases, a job object (`System.Management.Automation.PSRemotingJob`) is returned that you can manage with the various `*-Job` cmdlets - see [about_Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs).

**Jobs in PowerShell are *similar* to jobs in POSIX-like shells (such as Bash)**, but there are some **fundamental differences**, notably the **inability run *interactive* commands in the background** - see [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4267#issuecomment-320973486).

Background jobs use a *child process* that runs a hidden PowerShell instance in the background, which is slow and resource-intensive.

Therefore **consider the *thread*-based [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) cmdlet as a faster and more light-weight alternative** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56612574/45375).

**Syntax that works in PowerShell versions below 6 too, with `Start-Job`:**

```
# Preferable alternative: Start-ThreadJob
$job = Start-Job { docker run --rm -e DISPLAY=$using:DISPLAY firefox }
```

<sup>Note: `-ti` was removed, because, as [Nischay Goyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8090174/nischay-goyal) points out, it would open an *interactive shell session*, which means that the call wouldn't return until that session is manually closed. However, not that `Start-Job` generally doesn't support running interactive programs in the background, as [explained here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4267#issuecomment-320973486).</sup>

Note the need to refer to the `$DISPLAY` variable in the caller's scope via the `$using:` scope specifier - see [about_Remote_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7#using-local-variables).

Caveat: In PowerShell versions up to 6.x, background jobs started this way used a *fixed* working directory unrelated to the caller's - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53018311/45375).

**PowerShell [Core] 6+ alternative: placing `&` at the end of a command:**

```
$job = docker run --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY firefox &
```

Note that you do *not* need the `$using:` scope specifier with this syntax, and even in PowerShell 6.x the job sees the same working directory as the caller.

Note that there's **no similarly concise syntax for creating *thread* jobs  (the equivalent of a `Start-ThreadJob` call) yet as of PowerShell 7.0**, but adding one is the subject of [this feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9873).

---

As stated, you can use the various other `*-Job` cmdlets to ***manage* a job** once created (they also manage thread jobs created with `Start-ThreadJob`); for instance, the following command synchronously waits for the job to complete, prints its output, and then removes the job.

```
$job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

The postpositional `&` in `ping google.com &` didn't work, because you're running on *Windows PowerShell* (PowerShell versions up to v5.1), whereas this syntax requires PowerShell [Core] version 6 or higher.

[`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) is designed to launch an executable asynchronously, and in a new window by default (on Windows).
It is primarily useful for launching GUI applications (asynchronously) or running shell commands in a new console window.

While it can also launch processes invisibly, you get little control over that process, and its output can only be captured indirectly, via text files.

The reason your invocation failed is that you tried to pass the pass-through arguments *directly* to `Start-Process`, instead of passing them to the `-ArgumentList` parameter (as a single string, in the simplest case).

Answer (score 1):

The firefox command isn't expecting any input on stdin, and doesn't need a tty. So remove the `-it`. Next add `-d` which stands for detached mode, the standard way to run daemons inside of docker, or other non-interactive commands.

```
docker run -d --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY firefox
```

Comment: Thanks, however, note that this is a question more on Powershell than on docker. I.e., running any command with command line parameters under Powershell is my real question.

Answer (score 1):

To run the docker container in detached mode, please don't use `-it` as it opens the terminal and blocks it.

```
docker run --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY firefox
```

For running the command in background in PowerShell, As long as the command is an executable or a file that has an associated executable, use Start-Process (available from v2):

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow ping google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

to fully execute a command in docker with docker in background, you can use:

```
docker run $YourOption $ImageDocker exec $yourCommand
```

and don't use -i -t options, it opens terminal

do something like

```
docker run --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY firefox exec "ping google.com"
```